# R-Studio - Erro na instalação de pacotes

Tags: r

Tento instalar o pacote a partir do `.zip`, mas aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> R Tools for Biologists (RT4Bio)
>
> Funtions:
> rdiagnostic: Make a diagnostic residuals plot.
> plotbar: Use barplot2 from gregmisc package instead.
> gpsmanimport: Import coordinates from GPSMan Trajectories.
> plotmap: Make maps from gpsmanimport dataset.
> popgraph: Make populations graphs.
> survregraph: Make a survival graph.
> curve3d: Make a 3D plot using a similar syntax to the syntax of curve.
> volum: Make estimate volum of the nests termites arboreals.
> liquen: Make etimate area of the liquens.
> photoanalyzer: Make calculation of openness, coverage and aggregation of canopy trees through hemispherical photographs.
>
> use ?functionname for help.
>
> RT4Bio version 1.0 is now loaded

**Mensagens de aviso perdidas:**

> package ‘RT4Bio’ was built under R version 2.15.2

Answer (score 1):

Experimenta fazer `install.packages(file.choose(), repos=NULL)`. O comando `file.choose()` irá permitir escolheres o ficheiro `.zip` em causa.